# Changing the correct or incorrect value of a field in the Advanced custom field plugin and updating all posts

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields, acfpro

Unfortunately, I ran into a big problem.
We have about 4000 posts on the [TopOneMovie](https://toponemovie3.site), and we decided to change the value of one of the fields we created with the mentioned plugin, what I did was to change the default value of the field to the one I want. But until I update the posts, the value will not change.
Now I am looking for a solution to make the amount I changed affect all my posts. Can someone guide me? Thank you all in advance for your time.

Unfortunately, I can't think of any solution

Comment: Sounds like you need to run an SQL query. What is exactly the value you are trying to change across posts and how is it stored in the DB?

Comment: @billybadass Unfortunately I have no idea how is it stored in the database . It;s a true/false field , I want the value to be True in all posts .

Comment: It must be stored somewhere in `post_meta` have a search in db and let us know. Make sure you have a copy of everything a staging environment to try a few things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. With the **ACF Quick Edit Fields** plugin, you can edit the field values very easily.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-quickedit-fields/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).